# Скрытие системных папок от пользователей сайта

Tags: php, .htaccess

Возникла данная проблема.

У меня есть сайт на php. В структуре сайта имеются папки со стилями, скриптами, а также папка с обработчиками на php (например, там хранятся файлы соединения с БД, авторизации и регистрации).

Т.е.

```
css/
js/
img/
lib/
index.php
.htaccess
```

Суть в том, что любой желающий может получить доступ к этим файлам, просто прописав прямой путь к ним в адресной строке, соответственно, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы никто не мог напрямую попасть в такие папки, но при этом сам сайт мог отображать стили и обращаться к скрытым файлам.

Из того, что я применял:

```
1. <FilesMatch ~ "\.(php|htm|html|js)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

и просто 
  Deny from all
```

Закрывает доступ к папкам, но при этом другие страницы тоже не могут к ним обращаться, стили и картинки не отображаются.

```
2. Options All -Indexes
```

Все еще показывает файл, если ввести полный путь до него.

Итого мне нужно, чтобы index.php мог спокойно обращаться к содержимому папок css/, js/ и т.д., но при этом никто не мог достать эти файлы просто прописав в строке mysite.ru/css/style.css например.

Куча документации по htaccess прочитана, но я все не догоняю, как это реализовать.
Прошу сильно не бить чайника, а подсказать хотя бы ссылочкой на нужные ресурсы.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^folder/?$ - [F,L]` folder - папка, и файлы так же можно. Почитайте про RewriteRule

Comment: @InDevX почему-то не работает это правило

Comment: "Суть в том, что любой желающий может получить доступ к этим файлам, просто прописав прямой путь к ним в адресной строке" - **ничего страшного при этом не произойдет**. Надо оставить эти файлы в покое и найти себе какую-нибудь более реальную проблему для решения

Comment: ооо, я не дочитал вопрос до конца. всё еще хуже. мы не только РНР файлы защищаем от коварных злоумышленников, но и css тоже. впрочем, рекомендация остаётся та же самая

Comment: в общем, главное что надо понять - запросы к сайту делает не "index.php", а **браузер**.